# Create Dummy variables from multiple variables in python

Tags: python, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I am having trouble to create dummy variables from a dataset like this one:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'Temp':['Hot','Cold','Warm','Cold'],'Temp_2':[np.nan,'Warm','Cold',np.nan]
```

Note that the values are the same in both variables (Hot, Cold or Warm).

```
    Temp    Temp_2
0   Hot     NaN
1   Cold    Warm
2   Warm    Cold
3   Cold    NaN
```

So my problem is when using pd.get_dummies, the function does not take into consideration this relationship and codifies both variables independently.

```
    Temp_Cold   Temp_Hot    Temp_Warm   Temp_2_Cold      Temp_2_Warm
0       0           1           0              0               0
1       1           0           0              0               1
2       0           0           1              1               0
3       1           0           0              0               0
```

Is there a way I can codify it so i can get it like this?

```
    Cold    Hot Warm
0     0      1    0
1     1      0    1
2     1      0    1
3     1      0    0
```

Thanks,

Comment: One hot encoding means there should be only one `1` and remaining values `0` in a row for that column. Your logic is not suited using `get_dummies()`

Comment: I am wondering what will happen if there are 2 same values like `Hot` and `Hot` in a same row in that x dataframe?

Comment: Hi Prakash, actually the database i am using has up to four variables and cannot have a value duplicated in the same row.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'Temp':['Hot','Cold','Warm','Cold'],'Temp_2':[np.nan,'Warm','Cold',np.nan]})
print(x)
a = pd.get_dummies(x, prefix=['',''])
b = a.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()
print(b)
```

It is not so clean but works. Using prefix allows to have the same name in the columns generated from temp and temp_2.

```
   _Cold  _Hot  _Warm
0      0     1      0
1      1     0      1
2      1     0      1
3      1     0      0
```

Comment: Hey aurelien, thanks. I think the groupby worked for me!